# How to integrate terminal into javascript app

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Am currently building an application for windows and Linux and it requires the features of an integrated terminal just like vs code does, and my problem is, I have no idea how it is possible, please any suggestions, am using javascript.

Comment: have you looked at the source code of VSC, start a terminal and redirect the input/output

Comment: integrate a terminal in the browser window? what do you mean? you mean the developer tools?

Comment: are you using Node.js, Is your app Electron based like VSC,......